# Fix bugs in code through small update patch in android

Tags: android, debugging, patch, updates

I have an android app published on google play. I want to attain a programming approach so that if I got a reported bug from user side, I want to create a small patch (Please note that I am not publishing an update) to solve the bug. The app automatically download that patch and do the specific changes in the source code to remove the bug.

Comment: Google took a dim view of this when Facebook tried it: http://www.theverge.com/2013/4/26/4269074/google-play-store-ban-third-party-facebook-android-app-update

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible on Android.

Your app is installed to internal storage, and cannot modify its own dex file. To push out a bugfix, you must use an update through Google Play.